# Why am I unable to add multiple (identical) ViewControllers to my UIPageViewController without messing up my closure code?

Tags: swift

The set-up of my app is as follows:

**RootVC, which has a counter UILabel**

**A subContainer VC, "FirstVC" embedded within a UIPageViewController, which takes up the lower half of RootVC. FirstVC has a button, pressing which increases the UILabel on RootVC by one.**

Now I have used a closure to communicate between the 2 ViewControllers, which works fine initially, but when I try to add two more ViewControllers (SecondVC and ThirdVC) **both of which are absolutely identical to the FirstVC, and have a button each meant to do the same thing** (closure callback included), this throws an error for some reason, which I can't understand

The FirstVC (and the SecondVC & ThirdVC) is as follows:

```
class FirstVC {
    var buttonCallback: () -> Void = { }

    @objc func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        buttonCallback()
    }
}
```

My RootVC:

```
class RootVC: UIViewController {

    var tappedCount: Int = 0 {
        didSet { 
            label.text = "\(tappedCount)"
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let pageController = PageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal)
        pageController.buttonCallback = { self.tappedCount += 1 }
    }
}
```

And my UIPageViewController class is as follows:

```
class PageViewController: UIPageViewController {

var subViewControllers = [FirstSubVC(), SecondSubVC(), ThirdVC()] {
             didSet {
                 // just in case the controllers might change later on
                subViewControllers.forEach { $0.buttonCallback = buttonCallback } ////ERROR: Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'buttonCallback'////
             }
         }

  var buttonCallback: () -> Void = { } {
      didSet {
        subViewControllers.forEach { $0.buttonCallback = buttonCallback } ////ERROR: Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'buttonCallback'////
      }
  }

extension PageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return subViewControllers.count
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let currentIndex:Int = subViewControllers.firstIndex(of: viewController as! FirstVC) ?? 0
        if currentIndex <= 0 {
            return nil
        }
        return subViewControllers[currentIndex-1]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let currentIndex:Int = subViewControllers.firstIndex(of: viewController as! FirstVC) ?? 0
        if currentIndex >= subViewControllers.count-1 {
            return nil
        }
        return subViewControllers[currentIndex+1]
    }
}
```

I have tried to not cast the viewController as a FirstVC in the UIPageViewController extension but this creates another issue, and I don't believe this is the right way to solve this issue.

**EDIT**

```
protocol CallableThing {
var buttonCallback: () -> Void = { } //ERROR Property in protocol must have explicit { get } or { get set } specifier
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code cannot work. You have to identify the controller by a property, either use the `title` property or adopt the `Identifiable` protocol

For example

```
class FirstVC : UIViewController {

    func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "First"
    }

    var buttonCallback: () -> Void = { }

    @objc func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        buttonCallback()
    }
}
```

---

```
extension PageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return subViewControllers.count
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let currentIndex = subViewControllers.firstIndex(where: {$0.title == viewController.title}), currentIndex > 0 else { return nil }
        return subViewControllers[currentIndex-1]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let currentIndex = subViewControllers.firstIndex(where: {$0.title == viewController.title}), currentIndex <= subViewControllers.count-1 else { return nil }
        return subViewControllers[currentIndex+1]
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the errors still persist; all other code remained the same, except I changed the FirstVC, SecondVC & ThirdVC and improved upon my UIPageViewController extension as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with closures, nothing to do with communication. It's just a matter of types.

If you say, for example:

```
var subViewControllers = [FirstSubVC()]
```

Then `subViewControllers` is implicitly typed as `[FirstSubVC]` — an array of FirstSubVC. So every member of that array will be a FirstSubVC. So if FirstSubVC has a `buttonCallback` property, or *any* known property, then the compiler knows that *every* member of that array has one, and it is legal to say

```
subViewControllers.forEach { $0.buttonCallback = buttonCallback }
```

...because `$0` is a FirstSubVC, which has a `buttonCallback`, as we just established.

But if you say

```
var subViewControllers = [FirstSubVC(), SecondSubVC(), ThirdVC()]
```

Now what are all of those? What are they in common *typologically*? The compiler can conclude only that they are all *UIViewController subclasses.* So `subViewControllers` is typed implicitly as `[UIViewController]`. It's now just an array of plain vanilla UIViewControllers. That's all the compiler now knows about this array.

So now it is illegal to say

```
subViewControllers.forEach { $0.buttonCallback = buttonCallback }
```

because now `$0` is a UIViewController and no more, and a plain UIViewController has no `buttonCallback` property!

So you have two choices. The simplest, if they are really all identical, is to set up a common superclass. Let's say it's MyCallableVC, a UIViewController subclass. Give MyCallableVC a `buttonCallback` property. And make FirstSubVC, SecondSubVC, and ThirdSubVC subclasses of MyCallableVC:

```
class MyCallableVC : UIViewController {
    var buttonCallback: () -> Void = { }
}
class FirstSubVC : MyCallableVC {}
class SecondSubVC : MyCallableVC {}
class ThirdVC : MyCallableVC {}
```

So now when you say

```
var subViewControllers = [FirstSubVC(), SecondSubVC(), ThirdVC()]
```

`subViewControllers` is implicitly a `[MyCallableVC]` because that's what they all have in common. And if not, you can make it so:

```
var subViewControllers : MyCallableVC = [FirstSubVC(), SecondSubVC(), ThirdVC()]
```

Now your expression `$0.buttonCallback` is legal! `$0` is a MyCallableVC, which has a `buttonCallback` property.

The other possibility is to use a noninheritance type that they all have in common. That's called a *protocol*. You declare a protocol, let's say `CallableThing`, that requires a `buttonCallback` property. You make FirstSubVC, SecondSubVC, and ThirdVC *adopt* that protocol:

```
protocol CallableThing : UIViewController {
    var buttonCallback: () -> Void  { get set }
}
class FirstSubVC : CallableThing {
    var buttonCallback: () -> Void = { }
}
class SecondSubVC : CallableThing {
    var buttonCallback: () -> Void = { }
}
class ThirdVC : CallableThing {
    var buttonCallback: () -> Void = { }
}
```

And you *explicitly* type your array as an array of adopters of that protocol:

```
var subViewControllers : CallableThing = [FirstSubVC(), SecondSubVC(), ThirdVC()]
```

Now once again your expression `$0.buttonCallback` is legal, because now `$0` is a CallableThing, which by definition has a `buttonCallback` property.

Comment: Thank you so much, I finally understand what my mistake was. However, I purposely didn't follow the protocol approach because I could not get around the mandatory "get set" requirement in the definition of the property in CallableThing protocol. Is there a way to define the protocol without that? 
Edited the question to include my protocol code

Comment: Why do you want to define the protocol without it? That’s meaningless. This is a computer language, it has rules, you must obey them. It’s to be a var, just put `{get set}`. Anyway I think I’ve answered the question you asked.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean to offend you if that's what I've done. I have never used a protocol-delegation pattern in Swift before and so was just wondering how to define the property correctly within the Protocol. Not denying that you have indeed answered my question.

Answer (score -1):

It worked before because you have been force unwrapping a subViewcontrollers to FirstVC class when there was a single FirstVC class object. After adding additional controllers which were objects of classes SecondVC and ThirdVC, force unwrapping in pageViewController(*:viewControllerBefore:) and
pageViewController(*:viewControllerBefore:) leads to an error.

**Solution**

classes FirstVC, SecondVC and ThirdVC are subclasses of UIViewController and the code should reflect that fact.

Change this line of code

```
let currentIndex:Int = subViewControllers.firstIndex(of: viewController as! FirstVC) ?? 0
```

to

```
let currentIndex:Int = subViewControllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) ?? 0
```

---

```
class PageViewController: UIPageViewController {

var subViewControllers = [FirstSubVC(), SecondSubVC(), ThirdVC()] {
             didSet {
                 // just in case the controllers might change later on
                subViewControllers.forEach { $0.buttonCallback = buttonCallback } ////ERROR: Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'buttonCallback'////
             }
         }

  var buttonCallback: () -> Void = { } {
      didSet {
        subViewControllers.forEach { $0.buttonCallback = buttonCallback } ////ERROR: Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'buttonCallback'////
      }
  }

extension PageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return subViewControllers.count
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let currentIndex:Int = subViewControllers.firstIndex(of: viewController as! UIViewController) ?? 0
        if currentIndex <= 0 {
            return nil
        }
        return subViewControllers[currentIndex-1]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let currentIndex:Int = subViewControllers.firstIndex(of: viewController as! UIViewController) ?? 0
        if currentIndex >= subViewControllers.count-1 {
            return nil
        }
        return subViewControllers[currentIndex+1]
    }
}
```

**Improvements**

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    guard let currentIndex = subViewControllers.firstIndex(of: viewController),
        currentIndex > 0
    else {
            return nil
    }
    return subViewControllers[ currentIndex - 1]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the improvement suggestion, @Adobels. Unfortunately the errors still persist